# Dynamically adding angularjs directive with a $http to get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am actually stuck with an interesting problem,

I am trying to make soemthing of this sort:

> input key 1 , input value 1
>
> input key 2 ,  input value 2   < button to add more >
>
> < submit button >

Basically a user can click submit and issue a Get request to a given URL. now when he click to add more a new row appears with two input fields, where he can add more http get paarmeters.

I tried coding this up, but I am close to this: http://jsfiddle.net/d2jL2n35/1/

Could you please help me...

Two questions:

1. How to dynamically add a new row after the plus box is clicked?

   ```
   myApp.directive('options',function(){
   return {
       restrict:"E",
       template:"<div><input placeholder='params1' type='text'/><input placeholder='params2' type='text'><button><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i></button></div>"
   }
   ```

   })

Ok solved the first one by using $compile: http://jsfiddle.net/KyEr3/216/

2. How to get all the params and issue a get request?????

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want something like this:

## [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/d2jL2n35/11/)

#### View:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <options parameters="parameters"></options>
</div>
```

#### Controller:

```
var myApp =  angular.module('myApp',[])
.factory('yourAPI', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var submitResults = function (parameters) {
        return $http.get("http://wwww.whateverURL.com?" + parameters.map(function(parameter){return parameter.key + "=" + encodeURI(parameter.val) }).join('&'));
    };   
    return {        
        submitResults: submitResults
    }
}])
.directive('options', function(){
    return{
        restrict:"E",
        replace:true,
        template: 
            "<div><option parameter='parameter' ng-repeat='parameter in parameters'></option>"+
        "<div>"+
            "<input type='text' placeholder='key' ng-model='newKey' /> " +
            "<input type='text' placeholder='value' ng-model='newVal' /> " +
            "<button ng-click='addItem()'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i></button>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<input type='submit' value='submit' ng-click='sendRequest()' /></div>",
        scope: { parameters:'='},
        controller: function($scope, yourAPI){            
            $scope.newKey="";
            $scope.newVal="";
            $scope.addItem = function(){
                $scope.parameters.push({key:$scope.newKey, val:$scope.newVal});
                $scope.newKey="";
                $scope.newVal="";        
            };
            $scope.sendRequest = function(){
                yourAPI.submitResults($scope.parameters).success(function(data, status, headers) {           
                    console.log(data);
                });
            }   
        }

    }
})
.directive('option', function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        require: '^options',
        replace: true,
        scope: { parameter:'='},
        template: "<div>"+
                    "<input type='text' placeholder='key' ng-model='parameter.key' />" + 
                    "<input type='text' placeholder='value' ng-model='parameter.val' /></div>"
    }
})
.controller('mainController', function($scope){
    $scope.parameters=[];    
});
```

Notice that jsFiddle will block the get request, but this should work in your app.

Comment: The only issue with this example is that, this part would be replicated across many accordians, so there they would just have the same scope, and all will have the same number of input params.

Comment: @neoeahit oh, I see, my bad, I thought that you were making your life more difficult by trying to make everything with directives, but in this case, if you need to re-use it I guess that you would need the directives... Let me review my answer then.

Comment: I have gotton close to this: http://jsfiddle.net/KyEr3/216/

Any inputs on how to get all params using this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very rough example:

http://jsfiddle.net/d2jL2n35/9/

The crux of it is you have to store each set of values in an array, and reuse your directive to show them.  I removed your http call because I didn't want to sketch out the echo service.  But if you had a real service it could be like this:

```
$http.get('/options').success( function( result ) {
    $scope.options = result;
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're ready to upgrade to LEVEL 2 AWESOME ANGULAR HACKER!

Since your directives are so small, it might be easier as a beginner to only have one directive, instead of two. Directives are really great tools, but can make things more complex.

To get the data out of the inputs, you can use **ng-model** (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

So after copy-pasting your options' template into your `values` template, you can put a click event, that is `ng-click=addParam()` on the button.

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="addParam()>
```

JS:

```
$scope.param1 = null;
$scope.param2 = null;

$scope.addParam = function () {
  $http.get('some url', {param1: param1, param2: param2}).success(data) {
     // add another option row
  };
}
```

In this function, you're going to want to add another option row. One way to do this is have a for loop that creates a div for each ng-repeat, so you're template will look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="n in noptions">
  <input placeholder="params1" ng-model="param1" /> 
  <button ng-click="addParam()>
</div>
```

To add another option row, you can then add 1 to `noptions`, like `$noptions +=1`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

```
$scope.noptions = 0;

$http.get('some url', {param1: param1, param2: param2}).success(data) {
    $scope.noptions +=1;
 };
```

and another option row will be dynamically added.